# Running x11vnc on startup

Tags: 16.04

I'm extraordinarily new with using ubuntu.
But I'm trying to run a script to start x11vnc on startup.

I'm trying to use:

```
#!/bin/bash
x11vnc -rfbauth /home/myusername/.vnc/passwd
```

And putting that into start up applications.
The file is executable and runs if I double click it and choose to run in terminal.

Any ideas on what I should try next?

Answer (score 0):

[Have x11VNC start automatically via systemd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#Have_x11vnc_start_automatically_via_systemd_in_any_environment_.28Vivid.2B-.29)

I am on Artful (17.10) and this worked for me:

You will also need to edit `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` to include:

```
allowed_users = anybody
```

as the default is to console only. This is described here:

[Ubuntu Manpage for Xorg.wrap.4](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/Xorg.wrap.1.html)